# Beginner to Linux coming from Windows

Tags: programming, distro-recommendation

I have an Acer ES1-524 (2 core @ 2 GHz, 4 GB RAM, 500 GB HDD) pre-installed with Windows 10. I'm using it to learn programming but recently while using it with VSCode and a few Chrome tabs opened (I would say about 10 to 15 tabs), switching between applications takes a long time.

Which Ubuntu flavor would you recommend that's beginner friendly, works on a low-spec laptop, and usable in programming?

TL;DR

- No Linux experience
- Looking for an Ubuntu flavor because of the size of the
- Must be beginner friendly
- Must be low-spec friendly
- Must be able to handle VSCode with about 15 Chrome tabs opened

Comment: The different in flavors is the desktop (GUI) in use, plus toolkit underneath. I don't know what toolkit VSCode is written for, but if RAM/resources are limited (esp. <4GB) the applications like VSCode, Chrome being used should be considered (why have multiple toolkits in memory). Beyond that, it's mostly a user choice, and if you have >4GB of ram - your preferences probably carry matter more than toolkit.  Download a few and try them, see which you prefer, or watch videos of them.

Comment: This spec: 'Must be able to handle VSCode with about 15 Chrome tabs opened ' is rather independent of operating system. It depends on VSCode and Chrome and how much RAM is used to render the content in each tab. But the Ubuntu flavours with the smallest footprints are Lubuntu and Xubuntu. Try them live (booted from DVD or USB) before deciding what to install.

Comment: "Looking for an Ubuntu flavor because of the size of the" ??? You forgot the essential word (that I can't provide with an edit)

Comment: "Which Ubuntu flavor would you recommend that's beginner friendly, works on a low-spec laptop, and usable in programming? "  all are in essence the same. The best way to find the one you enjoy is to make lots of USB live session (that is how I did it: I made 10 USB live sessions and played with each for 30 minutes  :-) )

Answer (score 0):

I hate that I'm typing this in the answer box, but seeing that you HAVE declared a few things that are a must... I believe its warranted. My suggestion to you, with all things considered (your needs), would be Xubuntu. It will be familiar, great on low-spec hardware and once you're ready to go further with Linux, its VERY customizable. Thats only if you stick with it, and don't go to another DE (desktop environment) before then!

If you're feeling open, and would like to try a more (if a bit weird at first) productive workflow, with things like out-of-the-box easily accessible work spaces (think your windows in all four corners, but in a whole new window that you get to smoothly with two buttons on your keyboard), and things like a straight forward "doesnt take a hacker to use it" UI (user interface), then go with our beloved Ubuntu.

All in all though, my friend, it will be up to you one which one you choose to go with. There are so many different configurations here on this side of the fence, that there is no way in the world that one of us will be able to tell you which one makes you more productive. That's up to you.

Ciao!

Comment: The programming requirement is fulfilled by almost all Linux distros. You just need to install some various packages on them, depending on which one. A lot of stuff comes stock in Ubuntu, but your VSC (VS code) is downloadable from the official website, as a .deb package (think a .exe file on Windows, but different.

Comment: Visual Studio Code is in the Ubuntu Software app.

Comment: Yeah, but depending on which release that youre on, (and not considering snaps), it could be outdated

Comment: Visual Studio Code snap package is not outdated. It is very well maintained. In fact my VSCode was updated today.

Comment: Ok, nice. But lets not forget that this person is new, and after he installs that snap package on his very outdated (or at least low spec) hardware, how much of a surprise that it will be when he finds out it doesnt launch very fast, nor run the same as the non-container package.
  I was taking all things into account here.

Comment: Snaps don't launch slowly anymore. That problem has been fixed. The biggest problem with snap packages now is that too many snap packages are so buggy that they must be uninstalled.

Comment: I don't want this to turn into a chat because it keeps suggesting me to move it somewhere else. I would like to point out though, that i didn't suggest that the snap was outdated, I was actually excluding them from being so. Thats why I said "(not considering snaps) it could be outdated". 
  Also, why would you recommend someone install something like VSC from the repos,if its outdated, instead of the official package? jw. maybe I could learn from this.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/101873/discussion-between-karel-and-dps).